# Page structure using The Customizer Api

Tags: themes, theme-customizer, api

so I'm trying to customize themes using The Customizer Api, and I've noticed that I can only change the css, is there a way to control the page structure and layout (HTML) ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You do this through the php files in your theme folder.  I'd suggest you make a [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) first and then copy the files you want to change from the main theme to the child theme.  Make the changes there.

The other option is to change themes to one that already looks the way you prefer.

Comment: Hello @rudtek, I think I should've phrased my question better. What I want is to customize the Customizer Api so that the end user can freely manipulate the looks of his theme as wanted, so im familiar with the settings/section/controls, i want to use that to make the end user capable of changing the structure of the page's html not the css, but I figured you can do it all with css so that's what I'm gonna do, thanks for your reply.